# OCR character tracking

Tags: api, sdk, position, character, ocr

I need to be able to recognize a row of characters in an image and then track the positions of each number but have no idea where to start.

I don't want to write any of my own algorithms (unless I absolutely have to) so does anyone know of any API's or anything else that may help me with this or point me in the right direction?

Thank you :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[ABBYY Cloud OCR SDK](http://ocrsdk.com) will return you XML that contains both text and coorinates.

Disclaimer: I work for ABBYY

Comment: This needs to track multiple characters in realtime so reading from an xml is not really optimal. I need something fast that can run on a machine that doesn't necessarily need an internet connection. Thanks for your answer though.

Comment: OCR is very resource intensive process. How fast it should be? How many characters you should track per frame?

Comment: In the end there would be a machine dedicated to the tracking and quite a few characters but for now +- 15 and at a rate of about 30 fps

Comment: Well, hard to say will it work or not. I would recemmed you give a try to existing OCR Engines and see if they fast enough for your task. Recognition time depends a lot on pictures you will feed into it. In any case there still an option of using several CPU's as brute force to keep necessary speed. But Cloud OCR is not an option anyway, so you should start looking into off-line engines. Why not start from http://abbyy.com/ocr_sdk

Comment: I've taken a look at tesseract and managed to get it to work except for giving the character locations. For now I just want to get it working regardless of speed and at a later stage look into paid software. This is why I've been focusing on the open source packages. But I will take a look at abbyy and request a trial. Thank you :)